# How to update a hidden field's value in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, hidden-field

After Albert's brilliant answer about `GridView`s it became clear to me that the original wording of the question led to confusion. The `GridView` is just an element on the control - for all extents and purposes it could just be a button that has a value stored in a datatag.

For clarification purposes, I will post the full markup for the page and inner control, as well as the full code in it's current form.

Here's the `ascx` markup:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MyClasses.ascx.cs" Inherits="Utilities_CourseChange_MyClasses" %>

<style>
    .hiddenCol {
        display: none !important;
    }
</style>

<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div style="height: 8px;"></div>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hfTEST" runat="server" />
            <span style="width: 100%; display: inline-block; text-align: center; font-size: 8pt;">Tutor Groups</span>
            <asp:GridView ID="gvTutorGroups" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="sqlTutorGroups" DataKeyNames="TTGP_Group_Code" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="8" EmptyDataText="You have no tutor groups to display." Style="margin: 0 auto; width: 870px;" OnRowDataBound="gvTutorGroups_RowDataBound" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvTutorGroups_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-CssClass="hiddenCol" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hiddenCol">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hfTTGPISN" Value='<%# Eval("TTGP_ISN") %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="TTGP_Group_Code" HeaderText="TG Code" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="PRPH_Title" HeaderText="Name" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="TTGP_Start_Date" HeaderText="Start Date" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="TTGP_End_Date" HeaderText="End Date" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDummy" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>

            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlTutorGroups" runat="server" ConnectionString="My connection string" SelectCommand="My silly little database query - has two parameters, and spit out the values for the grid">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="<%$ AppSettings:CurrentAcademicYear %>" Type="String" Name="YearRef" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>

            <div style="height: 8px;"></div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Panel>
```

Now I could pull the `GridView` out of the `UpdatePanel` but I'm not sure what difference it would make.

In the code behind for the `ASCX', I have this:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Utilities_CourseChange_MyClasses : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void gvTutorGroups_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            //Change the mouse cursor to Hand symbol to show the user the cell is selectable
            e.Row.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "this.style.textDecoration='underline';this.style.cursor='Pointer'";
            e.Row.Attributes["onmouseout"] = "this.style.textDecoration='none';";
            e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(gvTutorGroups, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
        }
    }

    protected void gvTutorGroups_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gvTutorGroups.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowIndex == gvTutorGroups.SelectedIndex)
            {
                row.CssClass = "rowSelected";

                DataRowView dataItem = (DataRowView)row.DataItem; //An unreferenced remnant of a previous attempt that I forgot to delete
                HiddenField hfTGIsn = (HiddenField)this.Parent.FindControl("hfTGisn"); //Hidden field on the parent page, NOT the ASCX
                hfTGIsn.Value = ((HiddenField)row.FindControl("hfTTGPISN")).Value;
                hfTEST.Value = ((HiddenField)row.FindControl("hfTTGPISN")).Value; // I've put this in to test whether or not it's an issue with everything being reset, or just passing it up to the parent page that's playing up
            }
            else
            {
                row.CssClass = "";
            }
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            var loginName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToLowerInvariant().Trim().Replace("domainName", "");
            sqlTutorGroups.SelectParameters.Add("UserName", loginName);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I'm aware this isn't necessarily the best way of doing it - but it's a legacy system that we're maintaining while writing a new system in Blazor to eventually replace it. So I'm not necessarily looking for the best way of doing it, just a way that will work - I've lifted half of this code from other parts of the system to pull it into a centralised page.

Now the parent `ASPX` currently looks like this:

```
<%@ Page Title="Course Change Tool" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ProgCoachChangeRequester.aspx.cs" Inherits="Utilities_CourseChange_ProgCoachChangeRequester" EnableEventValidation="false" %>

<%@ Register Src="~/Utilities/CourseChange/MyClasses.ascx" TagName="Groups" TagPrefix="uc1" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="Server">
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfTGisn" runat="server" />
    <div class="content">
        <uc1:Groups ID="MyGroups" runat="server"></uc1:Groups>
    </div>

    <div runat="server" id="testDiv"></div>
</asp:Content>
```

With the code behind literally being as simple as:

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Utilities_CourseChange_ProgCoachChangeRequester : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        hfTGisn.Value = ((HiddenField)MyGroups.FindControl("hfTEST")).Value;
        
        testDiv.InnerText = hfTGisn.Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Now, everything in the `ASCX` seems to be working perfectly - my issue is that, when stepping through the code I can see the values being updated as I'd expect; but the end product in the dev tools window on Chrome indicates that, while the `hfTEST` (that hidden field I'd put in the ascx to test the mechanism) value is getting updated, the value for `hfTGisn` is not. As is evident in this screencap:
[image: Developer Tool representation of the rendered page after selecting a row]

I don't really care too much how I get the value into the parent ASPX (at this point, for all the hassle it's giving me, I'm half debating just pulling it all out of the ASCX and just shoving it all into the ASPX) - I just need the value so that I can start writing the rest of the page.

So, what's the easiest way to pluck the value from within the ascx, to the parent page?

---

Update with further attempt:

Following the suggestion of another answer, I attempted to utilise the `ViewState`, changing the code behind the `ASPX` page to:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    hfTGisn.Value = HfTGisn;

    testDiv.InnerText = HfTGisn;
}

public string HfTGisn
{
    get
    {
        return (string)ViewState["hfTGisn"];
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["hfTGisn"] = value;
    }
}
```

And changing the `gvTutorGroups_SelectedIndexChanged` method to:

```
protected void gvTutorGroups_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in gvTutorGroups.Rows)
    {
        if (row.RowIndex == gvTutorGroups.SelectedIndex)
        {
            row.CssClass = "rowSelected";

            HiddenField hfTGIsn = (HiddenField)this.Parent.FindControl("hfTGisn");
            hfTGIsn.Value = ((HiddenField)row.FindControl("hfTTGPISN")).Value;
            hfTEST.Value = ((HiddenField)row.FindControl("hfTTGPISN")).Value;
            ViewState["hfTGisn"] = hfTGIsn.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            row.CssClass = "";
        }
    }
}
```

But, seemingly the `ViewState` isn't populated in `Page_Load`

Comment: Maybe you could debug every method in code behind that is called after hidden field value is set. I suspect hidden field value might be reset later, in some of those calls.

Comment: @PoulBak - that'd be true if the `hfTGisn` was part of the `ASCX`; it isn't.

Comment: @MarkoRadivojević - the only other method that references the hidden field is the `Page_Load` which reads the value

Comment: Thank you for clarification. I've added one more edit to my answer, maybe it could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of multiple postbacks you could use `ViewState`.

Because web application is stateless, after a request the entire page and its controls are created again and the previous page, controls and their values are lost. `ViewState` helps managing the page's state.

You might try something like this:

```
public string HfTGisn
{
   get
   {
      return (string)ViewState["hfTGisn"];
   }
   set
   {
      ViewState["hfTGisn"] = value;
   }
}
```

In code behind add `HfTGisn` as `ProgCoachChangeRequester` partial class property.

In `Page_Load` add

```
hfTGisn.Value = HfTGisn;
```

In `gvTutorGroups_SelectedIndexChanged` event handler add

```
HfTGisn = ((HiddenField)row.FindControl("hfTTGPISN")).Value;
hfTGisn.Value = HfTGisn;
```

As ***Poul Bak*** stated, you can already access `ascx` control `hfTGisn` and I think it is the same for all other controls, including `hfTTGPISN`.

This way selected `ID` from `GridView` is saved in `HfTGisn` property (essentially stored in `ViewState`) and therefor it is not lost. `HfTGisn` property's value is then stored as value of `hfTGisn` hidden field, both in `gvTutorGroups_SelectedIndexChanged` event handler and in `Page_Load`.

You've said that `hfTGisn` hidden field's value is read in `Page_Load`, so I suppose you could read it directly from the property. Even more, you maybe don't even need the hidden field, if its only purpose is to store the selected `ID` from `GridView`.

This is quick fix, but I think it is more important to find where is the second postback coming from. I have no other idea than debugging every step after `gvTutorGroups_SelectedIndexChanged` is executed.

**Edit**: Maybe the simples solution is to read selected `ID` from `GridView` in `Page_Load`, and store it as hidden field's value. `GridView` and other controls store their value in `ViewState` by default.

**Edit 2**:
Thank you for clarification.

I didn't manage to reproduce the issue, I've successfully passed value from control to parent's hidden field.
However, I think there is a way to fix the problem you are facing, although the solution is far from good, but it works (at least I hope it will).

All other changes proposed in this answer should be rejected.

I still suspect hidden field's value is reset after some additional request. Instead of `ViewState` let's use `Session`. `ViewState` cannot be shared between page and its controls. `Session` can be shared through entire application, during single session.

In event handler store `ID` of `GridView` in `Session` and name it to be unique (you could store the name somewhere where you can access it easily from any part of code). Don't forget to store the value to hidden field, too:

```
protected void gvTutorGroups_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in gvTutorGroups.Rows)
    {
        if (row.RowIndex == gvTutorGroups.SelectedIndex)
        {
            // ...
            
            Session["Utilities_CourseChange_MyClasses_gvTutorGroups_SelectedIndexChanged"] = ((HiddenField)row.FindControl("hfTTGPISN")).Value;
            
            HiddenField hfTGIsn = (HiddenField)this.Parent.FindControl("hfTGisn");
            hfTGIsn.Value = Session["Utilities_CourseChange_MyClasses_gvTutorGroups_SelectedIndexChanged"];
            
            // ...
        }
        else
        {
            row.CssClass = "";
        }
    }
}
```

In `Page_Load` of the parent page store value from session to hidden field and it should be always executed, not only in case of postback:

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Utilities_CourseChange_ProgCoachChangeRequester : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        hhfTGIsn.Value = Session["Utilities_CourseChange_MyClasses_gvTutorGroups_SelectedIndexChanged"];
    }
}
```

Comment: asp.net controls, including text box, check box, and even gridviews maintain their viewstate automatic for you - in fact is this not quite much why we use and love asp.net and web forms? The gridview index ALSO persists. The the REAL question is why is it necessary to save the GV row index into a hidden control WHEN we already have the row index, and that means we have everything from that GV anyway - including the value we are to shove into hidden field - in fact ZERO of this code is required. In fact the GV selected index is not even required WHEN we find out how selected index as triggered

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal I agree with you. That's what I wanted to say in my edit I've made later.

Comment: My issue is that I seemingly CANNOT access that value (or anything else inside the `ASCX`) from outside of the `ASCX`

Comment: Turns out it was the update panels wreaking havoc (I'm not too sure how, but removing them fixed it) - I've pulled it out into the `ASPX` page now since it wasn't going to be used anywhere else anyway.... That said, your updated proposal seems to be working in a seperate test under the same conditions, so I'll flag it as accepted.

Comment: @AndrewCorrigan Thank you. It means a lot. The most important thing is the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, lots of issues here. And we will try explain a few:

First up, you don't show the grid view markup. Not the end of the world, but it certainly does incrase the completixty of this page - while simple, introduction of a GridView DOES introduce a signfiicnt amount of learning curve.

Next up:
You don't mention or note how you are triggering the selected index. Perahps you turned on the "select" button for this row?? (again: a BIG detail here).

Ok, so regardless, we ARE triggering the selected index event.

So, with that in mind, you can get the current grid view row like this with your code:

```
    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        GridViewRow MyGridRow = GridView1.Rows[GridView1.SelectedIndex];

        // to get NON templated colums of GV, you use:
        Debug.Print(MyGridRow.Cells[0].Text);

        // to get templated columns of GV, you use
        TextBox txtHotelName = MyGridRow.FindControl("txtHotelName") as TextBox;

        // you CAN NOT USE or GET the data time - it is OUT of scope, does not exist
        // DataItme ONLY exists DURING the data bind, NOT after. 

        // however, hftGisn is NOT in the grid view - so you are free to use and referance
        // that control like any other plane jane control on the web page.

        // eg:

        hfTGisn.Value = "some value goes here";

    }
```

So, if this is a templated column, you use find control.

So, if this is a bound field, then you MUST use .cells[] array.

Now, VERY often, we want to click on a row, and pass say the database primary key id, but we for sure do NOT want to display that key in the GV.

the best way to deal with that is to use the DataKeys feature. It is simple, easy, and ALSO is nice and secure since we don't have to hide, or even include that PK row  in the grid markup.

So, the way to approach this? Often I just drop in a plane jane regular asp.net button right into the markup.

Say, like this:

(and for demo, I put Hotel Name as a label - templated column, so we have a "mix" of data bound fields, a templated (label), and for good measure a plane jane asp.net button.

So, we have this:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="table"
            DataKeyNames="ID"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged1"  >
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName"    />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hotel Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="txtHotel" runat="server"
                            Text = '<%# Eval("HotelName") %>' 
                            Width="100px" >

                        </asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="cmdSel" runat="server" Text="View" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField> 
                </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Code to load is this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid();
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {
        string strSQL =
            "SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName, HotelName, Description " +
            "FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName";

        GridView1.DataSource = MyRst(strSQL);
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    public DataTable MyRst(string strSQL)
    {
        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }
        return rstData;
    }
```

And we now have this:

[image]

so, now all we have to do is add the code stub for the simple plane jane button click event.

While controls (and buttons) outside of the GV, you can just click on them, disaplay property sheet (or even double click on the button in design view, and you jumped to code behind.

However, you can't do that for controls inside of the GV, so, we have to flip into markup, and get Visual Studio to wire up that event.

You simple for the button type in onclick=, when you hit "=", the intel-sense pops up, and you THEN can choose to create the click event.

You see this:

[image]

So, choose create event - don't seem like happens, but you now have this:

```
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="cmdSel" runat="server" Text="View"
                            onclick="cmdSel_Click"
                            />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

And flip to code behind, and we can write this code:

```
    protected void cmdSel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btnSel = sender as Button;
        GridViewRow gRow = btnSel.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;

        Debug.Print("Row index click = " + gRow.RowIndex.ToString());

        // get database PK id of this row

        int? PKID = GridView1.DataKeys[gRow.RowIndex]["ID"] as int?;

        Debug.Print("Database PK row id = " + PKID.ToString());

        // Get first name - databound - so we use cells[] array

        Debug.Print("First name = " + gRow.Cells[0].Text);

        // get a templated column - hotel label

        Label lblHotel = gRow.FindControl("txtHotel") as Label;
        Debug.Print("Hotel name = " + lblHotel.Text);
    }
```

output:

[image]

As noted, we can NOT use the DataItem property here (to get the full underlying data row).

DataItem property is ONLY valid duriing the data bound event.

However, for the most part, it should not matter.

Since we have the grid view row, we can get ANY value displayed.

We can get the hidden database row PK id here ("id") in my example. Again, VERY nice, since we thus don't have to hide, try to save, or even include and display the database PK id, but it is managed automatic by the server side - no need to save or shove that value away some place, since once we have the GV row, then we get the row index, and with row index, we get datakeys value based on that row index.

So, now, we can say jump to another page, or even hide the GV in a "div" and then show a Repeater item, or Data View or whatever. And we probably should do that based on that PK id.

So, say on the same page, I dropped in a data repeater.

(but hidden), say this:

```
    <div id ="OneHotel" runat="server" style="display:normal">

    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div style="border-style:solid;color:black;width:400px;float:left;padding:8px">
            <div style="padding:5px;text-align:right">
            <p>Hotel Name: <asp:TextBox ID="HotelName" runat="server" Text ='<%# Eval("HotelName") %>' /></p>
            <p>First Name: <asp:TextBox ID="FirstName" runat="server" Text ='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>' /></p>
            <p>Last Name: <asp:TextBox ID="LastName" runat="server" Text ='<%# Eval("LastName") %>'    /></p>
            <p>City: <asp:TextBox ID="City" runat="server" Text ='<%# Eval("City") %>'  /></p>
            <p>Province: <asp:TextBox ID="Province" runat="server" Text ='<%# Eval("Province") %>'  /></p>
            Active: <asp:CheckBox ID="Active" runat="server" Checked = '<%# Eval("Active") %>'/>
            </div>
            <p>Description:
                <asp:TextBox ID="Description" runat="server" Text ='<%# Eval("Description") %>'
                    TextMode="MultiLine" rows="6" Columns="40" /></p>

            <asp:Button ID="cmdSave" runat="server" Text="Save" CssClass="btn"
                style="float:left"
                />
            <asp:Button ID="cmdCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CssClass="btn"
                style="float:right"/>
        </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
    </div>
```

Then in my gV button click above, we could add this code:

```
        OneHotel.Style.Add("display", "normal");
        GridView1.Style.Add("display", "none");

        Repeater1.DataSource = MyRst("SELECT * from tblHotelsA where id = " + PKID);
        Repeater1.DataBind();
```

Now, when I click on a row, I get this:

[image]

Or as noted, we could jump to another page.

So, once we have the grid row, from that we can get quite much anything we want - even a re-query of ALL of the row data to display columns etc. not necessary in the grid.

So, in summary:

You can drop in a plane jane button - just use a plane jane click event. You can use "namingcontainer" to get the grid row. Really, probablly nicer and clearner then using the built in selected index event.

You can NOT use DataItem property AFTER the databind() occures it will ALWAYS be null. You CAN use DataItem in and during events during binding (such as row data bound event).

You do NOT need to show, hide, tuck away the row click to get the database PK id that identifies the row - that is what the datakeys setting of GV is for.

## Edit: with above in mind?

Ok, so now that we have the index?

We are free to "shove" that index value into the hidden control.

For controls outside of the GV, we simply can reference them directly in our code, and no need for some kind of find control exists.

So, we would do this:

```
        Button btnSel = sender as Button;
        GridViewRow gRow = btnSel.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;


        Debug.Print("Row index click = " + gRow.RowIndex.ToString());
        hfTEST.Value = gRow.RowIndex.ToString();
```

Comment: While that is a brilliant explanation of `GridView`s, as per the edit of my question, the `GridView` itself is largely irrelevant to the issue at hand.

Comment: I thought the goal here was shove into the hidden field, our value, and see my 2nd edit, the solution then becomes   hfTEST.Value = gRow.RowIndex.ToString(); - which would shove/save the value into the hidden field. However, it not at all clear what the final purpose (or requirement) of the hidden field is for? With that information, my bets are a high chance exists that the hidden field would not be required. Code behind can continue to see/see/have the current selected index, and it should persist between post-backs. Often we do need previous index - to un-highlight with css.

Comment: Ok, so the issue of parent nesting seems at play. You can't use viewstate if this is a child page of master, but you can use session(). Session() is less then ideal, since if the user has two pages open, it make stomp on each other - but I would consider just using session() and give that a try. I however don't have 100% clear the nesting issue and problem - since I though both GV and the hidden field are on the same page, and thus a simple setting of that hidden field should work - but for code, session() would be easier - but less then ideal. I'll take a look later at your additional info

Comment: I think it was more to do with the fact the gridview was embedded in a user control which was used in a page, rather than directly being part of the page - if that makes sense?

Comment: I did note that - the user control. And that may well suggest you have to use .Parent, and then a find control on that parent. I not tested (attempted) to do this with a user control - but from what you posted - indeed you have "more" then just a GV on the form.  But, hidden fields do persist, and have their own viewstate, but you have a update panel - so if that event code runs in context of update panel, then viewstate does not apply to whole page - just the update panel. this suggest that modify of hidden field is better then using viewstate.

Comment: Hence why I eradicated the updatepanel in the end